# Spring Boot: failed to load JNDI variables into yml configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, jndi

According to [Spring Boot documentation about Externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), I tried to load a JNDI variable into my yml configuration file, like this:

```
spring:
  # Show or not log for each sql query
  jpa:
    show-sql: java:global/bc-api-immop/hibernate/show_sql
```

And it doesn't work.

I have my variable in my JNDI context:
[image]

I also tried this:

```
spring:
  # Show or not log for each sql query
  jpa:
    show-sql
      jndi-name: java:global/bc-api-immop/hibernate/show_sql
```

But, still the same result.
Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

As weird as it sounds, I also have this code, and it works:

```
spring:
  # Set here configurations for the database connection
  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/bc-appli-as400-ds
```

**Edit:** When I do this, it works to (so my issue really comes from getting my JNDI variable):

```
spring:
  # Show or not log for each sql query
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your yaml is the real problem here

The general concept is `key: value` so by writing `show-sql` spring boot expects a value of `true` or `false` as it appears on [Appendix A. Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) so it is normal that your property configuration fails and I am pretty sure that this is showing up somewhere in your log files.

On the first example when you write `show-sql: java:global/bc-api-immop/hibernate/show_sql` you are actually answering the question "*Should I show you the generated SQL statements*" with "*Hi spring Boot this is your datasource*" which we both understand it makes no sence to spring boot :)

Your last statement, on the other hand, is correct. You are defining under the yaml collection item `datasource` the property `jndi-name:` with value `java:jboss/datasources/bc-appli-as400-ds`

I would also suggest spending 10 minutes to read this article [Learn X in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

So a correct approach would probably be

```
spring:
  # Set here configurations for the database connection
  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/bc-appli-as400-ds
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

Let me know if I can help you more

Comment: I thank you for your answer. Actually, your last suggestion is what I had. But now, I want to configure the fact to show SQL (or not) depending on my JNDI variable. What I don’t understand is why with “jndi-name” attribute after “show-sql” it fails.

Comment: This is not possible. JNDI variable will provide you with the connections. show-sql refers to the JPA implementation and it has nothing to do with the actual connection. I think I am missing something regarding what you want to do. By the way if you liked my answer please mark it as acceptable :)